# How can I set JWT at the Frontend with bootstrap html not with react whilst the API is created with Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

Recently I am studying and building API with Django. I successfully set up the API of authentication system with Django API.
I am curious to know that is there any solution to add this JWT with frontend whilst the frontend only with bootstrap designed login form.
I don't want to use react or anything like that. Only through Django views is it possible to do?
It will be really helpful if there is any way to do. Or if it's required only js I will love to accept but I just want to call the templates login.html file not want to add any react or nodejs.
I searched online but everywhere either react or nodejs.

Here I am adding the features I am using of JWT in my code

```
#settings.py

from datetime import timedelta  # for JWT

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=360),
'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=90),
'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
# 'SIGNING_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
'AUDIENCE': None,
'ISSUER': None,
'JWK_URL': None,
'LEEWAY': 0,

'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}


#views.py

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['user_name'] = user.user_name
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['user_email'] = user.email
        token['user_mobile'] = user.mobile
        token['user_credit'] = user.point
        # ...

        return token


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer



#urls.py

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenRefreshView
from .views import MyTokenObtainPairView

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/login/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('auth/refresh-token', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='refreshtoken'),
]
```

If I missed any part of my coding to add here please let me know I will try to provide it here.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to access login API from external html?

Comment: Yes.
I want to access login API from external HTML form. Which will be considered as frontend and user will login through that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one will work. Put this in your html

```
<script>
        let email = 'get user email from input';
        let password = 'get user password from input';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'localhost:8000/auth/login',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'json',
            data: {email, password},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
            },
            error: function (XHR, status, err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I rendered my API to the template but when submitting it's showing 400 Bad Request

Comment: Add your errors too please.

Comment: Just showing the message that 400 Bad Request :(